# Rails engine: rake routes show its routes but on rspec execution "No route matches" is thrown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I'm trying to test a controller that is inside an engine my application is using. The spec is not within the engine, but in the application itself (I tried to test within the engine but also had problems).

My engine has the following routes.rb:

```
Revision::Engine.routes.draw do
  resources :steps, only: [] do
    collection { get :first }
  end
end
```

The engine is mounted on the application routes.rb normally:

```
mount Revision::Engine => "revision"
```

When I run `rake routes`, at the last lines I get:

```
Routes for Revision::Engine:
first_steps GET /steps/first(.:format) revision/steps#first
       root     /                       revision/steps#first
```

On my engine's controller (`lib/revision/app/controllers/revision/steps_controller.rb`), I have:

```
module Revision
  class StepsController < ApplicationController
    def first
    end
  end
end
```

On Rspec, I test this controller with:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe Revision::StepsController do
  it "should work" do
    get :first
    response.should be_success
  end
end
```

Then when I run this spec, I get:

```
ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches {:controller=>"revision/steps", :action=>"first"}
```

To be sure that the route doesn't really exist, I added this to the spec:

```
before do
  puts @routes.set.to_a.map(&:defaults)
end
```

And the result is this:

```
[...]
{:action=>"show", :controller=>"devise/unlocks"}
{:action=>"revision"}
```

It has only the `:action` parameter.

What may be wrong?

Answer (score 4):

When you're trying to test an engine's controllers, you need to specify what route set you want the controller test to use, otherwise it will run it against the main app's. To do that, pass `use_route: :engine_name` to the `get` method.

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe Revision::StepsController do
  it "should work" do
    get :first, use_route: :revision # <- this is how you do it
    response.should be_success
  end
end
```

Comment: Agreed. Note that this is true only if the Engine has an isolated namespace.

Comment: This helped me on an issue that wasn't even Rails engine related. I was trying to access a collection route nested inside of a resource, and the only way I could get it to recognize the action with a valid route is to pass in `use_route: :name_of_route`. Thanks!